# use uncaughtException dialog on activity android

Tags: java, android

my device sometimes misses the camera, so unfortunately , my app has stopped message appears and app dies.

so, I try use `uncaughtExceptionhandler` I want to show the logcat dialog .

recently ,

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceStae) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnhandledExceptionHandler(this));
```

UnhandledExceptionHandler.java

```
public class UnhandledExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private static final String TAG = "UnUnHandler";
private final Activity activity;

public UnhandledExceptionHandler(final Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread unusedThread, final Throwable e) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String title = "Fatal error: " + getTopLevelCauseMessage(e);
            String msg = getRecursiveStackTrace(e);
            TextView errorView = new TextView(activity);
            errorView.setText(msg);
            errorView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 8);
            ScrollView scrollingContainer = new ScrollView(activity);
            scrollingContainer.addView(errorView);
            Log.e(TAG, title + "\n\n" + msg);
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener =
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            System.exit(1);
                        }
                    };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setView(scrollingContainer)
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit", listener).show();
        }
    });
}

private static String getTopLevelCauseMessage(Throwable t) {
    Throwable topLevelCause = t;
    while (topLevelCause.getCause() != null) {
        topLevelCause = topLevelCause.getCause();
    }
    return topLevelCause.getMessage();

}

private static String getRecursiveStackTrace(Throwable t) {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
    return writer.toString();
}
```

and I run my code.
first, if my device  misses the camera , the app doesn't die.
but not showing activity and logcat dialog.

I want to show logcat dialog on my app activity

How can I do this programatically ?

logcat

```
tTTTTTTFatal error: startPreview failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.video.CameraLiveView.cameraPlayStart(CameraLiveView.java:202)
at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.video.CameraLiveView.surfaceCreated(CameraLiveView.java:116)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1867)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

//Global variable
  private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
  private Camera mCamera;
  private boolean playing = false;

public boolean cameraPlayStart() {

```
    if (mHolder == null) {

        return false;

    }
    try {

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startFaceDetection();
        mCamera.startPreview();    //occur error

        playing = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}


    @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
cameraPlayStart();//occur error 
}
```

Comment: just in case you didn't know I wanted to tell you that you can view the logcat from the IDE you are using, and it is not advised to view the logcat to the user

Answer (score 1):

You need to show your AlertDialog by adding

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: thanks, I adding `AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create(); alertDialog.show();`     under the `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)` ?

Comment: Such as previous results, app not die but not showing dialog

Comment: Just to be sure, your log statement, Log.e(TAG, title + "\n\n" + msg);, prints out and the AlertDialog doesn't show. Is that correct?

Comment: I try your advice,  `Log.e(TAG, title + "\n\n" + msg);;    recently startPreview failed, but sometime occur fail to camera service error.  my logcat update post

Comment: Well, you already had the log statement in the run method. I don't know why your AlertDialog isn't showing. I think you should edit your question to state that your log statement is posting so you definitely know that the run() method is executing, but aren't sure why the AlertDialog isn't showing. While you're waiting, you could try moving the AlertDialog code into onCreate and make sure that it would show if it were called from the UI thread. Temporarily, you might want to force an exception every time so your run() method runs every time. Sorry, I don't know why AlertDialog isn't showing.